# how to change button click event using code

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

need some help what is wrong in this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Button1.ID = "Button4"; 
    Button2.ID = "Button1"; 
    Button1.Click -= Button1_Click;
    Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click); 
    //Button2.ID = "Button1"; 
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Response.Write("success"); 
}
```

When i click on button1, it calls button1_click and when i click on button2, it also calls button1_click instead of button2_click.

i want to call button2_click on botton2 click after button1 event exicution

Comment: You really need to work on your code style. There’s virtually no way to spot errors in that mess. As a service, I fixed it.

Comment: Check the difference between `=` and `+=`.

Comment: @DanielB i'm not suggesting that somebody shoudln't indent, but when a method has only one line, it's really not that unreadable if if the line isn't indented. And when 2 similar statements that are very simple are on one line, again, far from unreadable.  And when a method has nothing in its body and the { } are on the same line with the header, again that is far from unreadable. It's not convention and it wouldn't be recommended but to say it's "virtually impossible to spot errors" is really far from reality.

Comment: This line looks really odd "Button1.Click -= Button1_Click;"  when done without the Button1_Click method.  If you are really asking how to change the button click event to something else when a button is clicked then you should amend your title to make it clearer that's what you're asking 'cos that's a bit more interesting than just how to change a button click event using code (which could be done at any point not just when a button is clicked).

Comment: @barlop It’s all about routine. Straying from established code style hampers readability tremendously. It’s of course different when it’s just a hobby and nobody is ever going to work with that code, but at work stuff like that just don’t fly. I’ve worked with a lot of poorly formatted legacy code. It’s shit. Luckily Visual Studio (Ctrl+E, D in C# “mode”) or ReSharper can rectify this in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @DanielB  As I said,  "I'm not suggesting that somebody shoudln't indent"    And I said "It's not convention and it wouldn't be recommended"     And I never suggested that such a thing would "fly" in the workplace or even would be fine in a hobby.  Please re-read my comment.

Comment: @barlop why suggest it then? It is readable code I see no problems with this question

Comment: i@DavidBeaumont  I don't think you understood.  Daniel edited it and improved the indentation. Not me.  (that was when it was on superuser)  The original is here http://i.imgur.com/kobQnnW.png

Comment: out of interest, what is the reason for you setting the ID attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have added a handler on Button1_Click to Button2_Click like below:

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click);
```

It is worth mentioning that these events are normally automatically added when you double click the button itself in the design view, also the method is created.  So these buttons may already have their own even handlers created in the designer file.

Comment: I have found I can add events by something like `button1.Click=MyMethod;`  and that would be far more concise.

Comment: Yes you can, however concise - I disagree with, especially for events that are fired from the UI.  There is a reason why they are automatically created in the designer file, this way the handler is created in a centre location and is grouped by the controls properties.  Also it is created upon initialise.

Comment: Yes well if he uses the line you wrote/quoted (which is less concise) Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click); , then it's still not going to be in the designer file either.    So i'm saying that if you are going to programmatically add an event, you may as well use the simpler and more concise notation.  And he was asking about programmatically doing it, hence his use of +=.   And of course i'm not suggesting that programmatically adding events is more concise than visual studio's automatic adding of events which doesn't show up in the main code at all.

Comment: Your answer is unclear and doesn't really address what he asked,  because the way you introduced your question it sounded a bit like you were recommending a line to him but actually the one line of code you have in your answer is just a copy/paste of one of his lines, so if you were suggesting a correction to him, you haven't written it.  If you're saying he should be letting VS auto generate events, well,  you haven't addressed his question where he's asking about dealing with events in code. You're right though that we don't know what events he has autogenerated.

Comment: You cannot answer this question without additional information however you can explain why the explained behaviour is occurring which is what I have done

Comment: You write "You have added a handler on Button1_Click to Button2_Click" and then you show the code he used `Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click); `   <--- That doesn't look like a description of his code. His code there which you introduced, is adding to Button1.Click not to Button2.Click.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button1.Click -= new EventHandler(Button1_Click); // remove Button1_Click
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(Button2_Click); // add    Button2_Click
```

Good luck !